# OnClick() is not working for currency converter.

Tags: android, fragment

I want to add currency converter in side menu of my app. But i am unable to get conversion after on click().
On click "calculate" i am not getting conversion.
Please see the code why i am not able to click . I have used yahoo api.

CurrencyConverter.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.R;


public class CurrencyConverter extends Fragment {
    public CurrencyConverter() {
    }
    TextView t;
    public int to;
    public int from;
    public String[] val;
    public String s;
    public Handler handler;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currency_converter, container, false);
        t= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner s2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this.getActivity(), R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        val = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(1));
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(2));

        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View rootView) {


//t.setText(exResult);
                if (from == to) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", 4000).show();
                } else {
                    try {
                        //  s = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22"+val[from]+val[to]+"%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
                        JSONObject jObj;
                        jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                        String exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");
                        t.setText(exResult);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }




        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public class calculate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                s = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22"+val[from]+val[to]+"%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
                JSONObject jObj;
                jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                String exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");
              //  t.setText(exResult);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return s;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String exResult) {
           //  t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         //  t.setText(exResult);
        }

       }

    public String getJson(String url)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String con;
        while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            build.append(con);
        }
        return build.toString();
    }

        public class spinOne implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
        {
            int ide;
            spinOne(int i)
            {
                ide =i;
            }
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int index, long id) {
                if(ide == 1)
                    from = index;
                else if(ide == 2)
                    to = index;

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

    }
}
```

CurrencyConverter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/equal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="122dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="@string/result"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calculate" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: image of main menu]
[image: & after click currency converter]

Error:

```
05-09 17:33:30.425 2238-2238/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley, PID: 2238
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                     at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.CurrencyConverter$1.onClick(CurrencyConverter.java:74)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-09 17:33:30.430 1233-1513/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley/.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated Answer:

CurreencyConverter.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.R;


public class CurrencyConverter extends Fragment {
    public CurrencyConverter() {
    }
    TextView t;
    public int to;
    public int from;
    public String[] val;
    public String s;
    String exResult;
    public Handler handler;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currency_converter, container, false);
        t= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner s2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this.getActivity(), R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        val = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(1));
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(2));

        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View View) {



                if (from == to) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", 4000).show();
                } else {
                    new calculate().execute();

                }
            }

        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public class calculate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                s = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22"+val[from]+val[to]+"%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
                JSONObject jObj;
                jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                 exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return exResult;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String exResult) {

           t.setText(exResult);
        }



       }

    public String getJson(String url)throws  IOException {

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String con;
        while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            build.append(con);
        }
        return build.toString();
    }

        public class spinOne implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
        {
            int ide;
            spinOne(int i)
            {
                ide =i;
            }
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int index, long id) {
                if(ide == 1)
                    from = index;
                else if(ide == 2)
                    to = index;

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke String from UI thread that has no connection to it. As one of the possible workarounds you can create global variable and assign to it at

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String exResult) {
           //  t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         //  t.setText(exResult);
             globalString = exResult;
        }
```

Afterwards you can use it code. Please read about [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) lifecycle and `Android Threads`.

Comment: didn't get Please post code where i am going wrong .

Comment: lets start from zero. First of all:                         jObj = new JSONObject(s);
this line refers to variable that is not initialized.

Comment: yes you are right ,But please tell me  should i call onClick() in the doInBackground()?